# I am trying to fetch data from database and place it in a ListView in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to create a quiz app which contains 1 question and 4options for that I created a database from which the questions and options are fetched to 5 textviews using `ListView`. I surfed many tutorials and using a page from stackoverflow created it using `ArrayList` and `Cursor` but i am getting a 
error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.shark.shopapp.merge.getData(merge.java:26)
            at com.example.shark.shopapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
```

It is showing in a Cursor.query() line. MainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.ques_layout);  db=openOrCreateDatabase("check1.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE que(ques TEXT,optn1 TEXT,optn2 TEXT,optn3 TEXT,optn4 TEXT)");
ListView l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
merge mer=new merge(this);
ArrayList<String> data=mer.getData();
l1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.ques_layout,data));
db.close();
```

Merge.java:

```
public merge(Context c){ourContext=c;}
    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ques, optn1, optn2, optn3, optn4};
        Cursor c2=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        int ques = c2.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int optn1 = c2.getColumnIndex("optn1");
        int optn2 = c2.getColumnIndex("optn2");
        int optn3 = c2.getColumnIndex("optn3");
        int optn4 = c2.getColumnIndex("optn4");
        for (c2.moveToFirst(); !c2.isAfterLast(); c2.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(c2.getString(ques) + c2.getString(optn1) + c2.getString(optn2) + c2.getString(optn3) + c2.getString(optn4));
        }
        db.close();
        return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is line number 26  in Merge??

Comment: Line number 26 is Cursor c2=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
String strQuery="select option from (select option1 as option from table
union all
select option2 as option from table
union all
select option3 as option from table
union all
select option4 as option from table) as result";
Cursor c2 = db.SelectQuery(strQuery);
String[] from ={"option"};//you can add as many as you need.
in[] to to = {"R.id.TextViewID"};//you can add as many as you need.
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(youractivityname.this,R.layout.listviewlayout,c2,from,to);
yourlistview.setAdapter(sca);

Comment: Should i add this code to MainActivity  or to merge class?

Comment: in your code your trying to list all five option in your listview right?
if that's the case merge class is not needed just run my code in mainactivity oncreate

Comment: Ya right.In the MainActivity validated like t1=(TextView)findviewbyid(r.id.textview4);

Comment: if that's the case merge class is not needed just run my code in mainactivity oncreate

Comment: ow sorry i think i miss understood your question are you trying to display five different field in just one listview ?

Comment: if that's the case i think it's much easier if you just use different listview per item or display your options in a button

Comment: you can display your options in listview using my code but it will look like this | option1 | option2 | option3 | option4 |

Comment: i want options to be displayed one by one.as its based on quiz.

Comment: uhm you can use my code but you should change your query and use unionall

Comment: select option from (select option1 as option from table
union all
select option2 as option from table
union all
select option3 as option from table
union all
select option4 as option from table) as result

Comment: Actually i edited your code and it works fine.1 probz is it fetches all the rows at once.can you tell me how to fetch one by one on a click of a button?i placed the adapter inside onClick().It would be grateful if u help with that plz.

Comment: i've edited my my answer.  try it i hope it will give the result that you've wanted.

Comment: No before itself it fetched all the options.No need to give like option1 option2 option3 option4 separately.I want to know how to fetch row one by one.

Comment: uhm can you send me a print screen of your code and layout ? so i can easily understand what to do thanks if you want just send it to my email bs.agapitz@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
_cursor = _database.rawQuery("select * from "+YOUR_TABLE_NAME, null);

                _cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                while(_cursor.isAfterLast() == false){

                    _idDB =  _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_ID));
                    _ivrsDB =  _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_IVRS_NUM));
                    _readingDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_METER_READING)); 
                    _imageDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_IMAGE));
                    _userIdDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_USER_ID));
                    _latDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_LAT));
                    _longDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_LONG));
                    _dateDB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_DATE_TIME));
                    _mob1DB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_MOB_FIRST));
                    _mob2DB = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_MOB_SECOND));
                    _reasonSelected  = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_REASON));

                    //need to call UPDATE WS
                    updateDataFromDB(context, _idDB , _ivrsDB , _readingDB, _imageDB, _userIdDB , _latDB , _longDB, _dateDB , _mob1DB , _mob2DB
                            ,_reasonSelected);


                    System.out.println("Id from DB=" + _idDB);
                    System.out.println("IVRS NUMBER="+ _ivrsDB);
                    System.out.println("Reading="+ _readingDB);
                    //System.out.println("Image Path="+_cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(MySqliteHelper.READING_DETAILS_COLUMN_IMAGE)));
                    System.out.println("USer ID="+_userIdDB);
                    System.out.println("LAT="+_latDB);
                    System.out.println("LONG="+_longDB);
                    System.out.println("DATE="+ _dateDB);
                    System.out.println("MOb 1="+_mob1DB);
                    System.out.println("Mob 2="+_mob2DB);
                    System.out.println("Reason from db =" + _reasonSelected);




                    _cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                _cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `db` variable is not initialized in `merge`.

Assuming you're using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, call e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` on the helper object to get an `SQLiteDatabase` object you can assign to `db`.

Comment: No i am not using SQLiteOpenHelper but can you tell me is this right?Sqlite.openDatabase(DATABASENAME,null,0)